# Non-terminating while loop

Tags: c++, while-loop

I was just wondering something. I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number, largest, counter = 1;
    while (counter <= 10)
    {
          cout << "Enter a number: ";
          cin >> number;
          if (counter = 1)
          {
               largest = number;
          }
          else if (number > largest)
          {
               largest = number;
              }
          counter++;
    }
    cout << "\n\nThe largest number is: " << largest;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The thing is, it never terminates. I did manage to fix the problem by modifying the code a little, but I was wondering why this happened. Here is the fixed code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number, largest, counter = 1;
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> number;
    largest = number;
    while (counter < 10)
    {
      cout << "Enter a number: ";
      cin >> number;
      if (number > largest)
      {
           largest = number;
      }
      counter++;
    }
    cout << "\n\nThe largest number is: " << largest << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

It seems that after removing the else if statement it worked. What happened?

Comment: Doesn't the compiler give you a warning?

Comment: If I'd be the compiler I'd say like "Cannot implicitly convert type `int` to `bool`" or like "you shouldn't set a variable in `if`" or like "hey Emile wazzup why use only one `=` in `if`?Try `==`."

Comment: @JohnnyCageWins. My compiler (MSVC) says something along the lines...

Comment: @Armen say hi from me ^^

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if (counter = 1)
```

this should be

```
if (counter == 1)
```

otherwise, you're going to reset your counter to 1 each iteration.

Answer (score 4):

A common mistake:

```
if( counter = 1) // assignment operator
```

This will set `counter`'s value to `1` at each iteration, and the loop never finishes.

You should use

```
if( counter == 1) // equality operator
           ^^^^
```

which is exactly what you mean

Answer (score 4):

`if (counter = 1)` reassigns 1 to counter every loop this being always `< 10`.

You want `if (counter == 1)`.

Answer (score 3):

```
  if (counter = 1)
```

This does not compare `counter` and `1`, it assigns `1` to `counter` and then checks `counter`- which we just set to `1` so it will always be positive and always be `<= 10`.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
if (counter = 1)
```

Should be

```
if (counter == 1)
```

since you want to compare, not to assign value.

Answer (score 1):

Your first example had

```
if (counter = 1)
```

instead of

```
if (counter == 1)
```

so the if statement would reset counter to 1 during each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

As other notice, this is a common error. Your could avoid it by typing

```
if( 1 == counter )
```

instead of

```
if( counter == 1 )
```

since

```
if( 1 = counter )
```

would not compile (if you made the error and forgot an '=').

Comment: IIRC the Debian hack was implemented by changing an equality to an assignment. Since then, it may look backward, but I'm a big fan of constant-lvalue comparison.

Comment: Personal opinion, but I hate and loathe than construct. Compiling with warnings enabled will catch this particular error. Code analyzers will catch instances that the compiler won't catch such as `if ((counter = 1)) ...` Don't make me write things bass-ackwards.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
if (counter = 1)
```

Assignment instead of comparison. Compile with higher warning level.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (counter = 1)
```

So, `counter` value is 1 forever.

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning 1 to counter rather than comparing it, use == instead of =